# Defining function from table

Tags: functions, function-construction, list-manipulation

I have a table of values of the form

```
Table[{i1,j1}, {i2,j2}...]
```

and I want to define a function like `f[i]` to take the values from the table, i.e. `f[i2] = [j2]` and so on. Can I do this in *Mathematica*?

Comment: You want to use `Interpolation`

Comment: You could do either this `f = <|Sequence @@ Rule @@@ Table[{x[i], y[i]}, {i, n}]|>` or `Map[f[#[[1]]] = #[[2]] &, Table[{x[i], y[i]}, {i, n}]];`.

Comment: It is not clear what is your `Table[...]`. Is it the way your create your list of pairs ? Give a more precise example.

Comment: `f[i2]=[j2]` means nothing. You did not correct your question and already accepted the first answer. I am voting to close.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
table = Table[{ToExpression["i" <> ToString@n], ToExpression["j" <> ToString@n]}, {n, 5}]
```

$\ $`{{i1, j1}, {i2, j2}, {i3, j3}, {i4, j4}, {i5, j5}}`

```
(f[#1] = #2) & @@@ table
```

$\ $`{j1, j2, j3, j4, j5}`

```
?f
```

[image]